# How to pass a template function to another function and apply it

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

```
// I can't change this function!
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void RpcWriteKafka(Function func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// I can change this one if necessary.
template<typename FUNC, typename... Args, typename CALLBACK, typename... CArgs>
void doJob(std::tuple<CALLBACK, CArgs&&...> tp, FUNC func, Args&&... args) {
    // SetValues(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::apply(func, tp);
}

int main() {
    doJob(std::make_tuple([](int i){}, 1), RpcWriteKafka, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, some library provided the template function `RpcWriteKafka`. It needs the parameter about a callback function(`func`) and its parameters(`args...`).

I want to define my own function `doJob`, which allows me to call it like this: `doJob(std::make_tuple([](int i){}, 1), RpcWriteKafka, 1);`. I'm expecting that the first parameter, which is a `std::tuple`, could be passed to the second parameter `RpcWriteKafka`.

Why do I used `std::tuple`: [How to pass a function with parameter pack to a function with parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72186025/how-to-pass-a-function-with-parameter-pack-to-a-function-with-parameter-pack/)

For now, it can't be compiled.

The compiler generated two errors:

1. `mismatched types 'CArgs&&' and 'int'`, which comes from the `1` in that tuple;
2. the second parameter `RpcWriteKafka` is `unresolved overloaded function type`.

So how to solve the two issues? Is it possible to define such a function `doJob` so that I can call it easily as shown in the `main` above?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you with `CArgs&&` in the linked question, 康桓瑋 is right

Comment: @Caleth No problem man. You can update your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the first parameter type of `doJob` should be `std::tuple<CALLBACK, CArgs...>` instead of `std::tuple<CALLBACK, CArgs&&...>` since `CArgs&&`
cannot be deduced in such context.

Second, since `RpcWriteKafka` is a *function template*, you can't pass it to `doJob` like this, instead, you need to wrap it with lambda, so this should work (I omit the `Args&&...` because it is not used)

```
template<typename CALLBACK, typename... CArgs, typename FUNC>
void doJob(std::tuple<CALLBACK, CArgs...>&& tp, FUNC func) {
  std::apply(func, tp);
}

int main() {
  doJob(std::make_tuple([](int i){}, 1), 
    [](auto... args) { RpcWriteKafka(args...); });
}
```